# Установка mechanize в pythonanywhere

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, бот, pythonanywhere

Решил развернуть чат-бота для ВКонтакте в pythonanywhere:

1. Создал окружение при помощи `virtualenv test_env`
2. Загрузил все файлы через «Upload file»
3. Установил vk_api при помощи `pip install --user vk_api`

Когда запустил через bash-консоль файл, получил обратно traceback, в котором python не может найти модуль *_mechanize*:

```py
~$ python3.6 test_env/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_env/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cases, keyboards, traceback
  File "/home/MyName/test_env/cases.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mechanize import Browser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mechanize/__init__.py", line 122, in <module>
    from _mechanize import \
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_mechanize'
```

Пробовал запускать с разных версий, обновлял mechanize с помощью `pip install --upgrade --user mechanize` — не помогло. Пытался установить этот самый *_mechanize* с нижним подчёркиванием в начале:

```py
~$ pip install --user _mechanize
Invalid requirement: '_mechanize'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 78, in __init__
    req = Requirement(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 96, in __init__
    requirement_string[e.loc:e.loc + 8]))
InvalidRequirement: Invalid requirement, parse error at "'_mechani'"
```

Решения проблемы не нашёл, поэтому обращаюсь сюда, в Stack Overflow

Comment: @Komdosh, модуль уже предустановлен в окружении. Я уже апгрейдил его — не помогает

Comment: Нужно активировать виртуальное окружение, а потому же запускать файл main.py

Comment: @insolor,
`~$ source test_env/bin/activate
(test_env) ~$ python3.6 test_env/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_env/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cases, keyboards, traceback
  File "/home/MyName/test_env/cases.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mechanize import Browser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mechanize/__init__.py", line 122, in <module>
    from _mechanize import \
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_mechanize'`

Результат тот же — python не находит модуль *_mechanize*